# Formato de salida de string en Java

Tags: java

Dispongo de dos clases, denominadas respectivamente `Products` y `PackageOfProducts` que representan productos y un paquete, el paquete permite disponer de varios productos agrupados. Me encuentro buscando una solución alternativa al problema de devolver una string con los nombres de los productos de los que está formado el paquete separadon dichos productos por una coma y un espacio en blanco (", "). Adjunto la forma que se me ocurrió.

```
    ArrayList<Products> packageOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(Products i : this.packageOfProducts) {
            sb.append(i.getName()).append(", ");
        }
        return "[" + sb + "];
    }
```

***Resultado obtenido:***

`[Product1, Product2, Product3, ]`

**Problema del resultado obtenido:**

Como se puede ver, el resultado obtenido anteriormente incluye una `,` pese a que se ha alcanzado la longitud máxima del array y no existen más elementos que separar.

Comment: Por otro lado, `package` es una palabra reservada en java. Por favor, usa otro nombre para tu variable.

Comment: *el paquete permite disponer de varios productos agrupados* ... Si tal es el caso, considera crear un método en la clase que agrupa los productos, desde el cual obtengas lo que quieres, así, sólo llamarías: `laInstanciaDelPaquete.elMetodoQueMuestraTodosSusProductos()`Dicho eso, cuando vayas concatenar cadenas en un bucle considera usar  `StringBuilder`, que es mucho más eficaz que `+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtén la lista de nombres y simplemente convierte esa lista a `String`. Quedaría:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
   return packageOfProducts.stream().map(Products::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toString();
}
```

O bien:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return packageOfProducts.stream().map(Products::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

Te adjunto un demo que puedes [ejecutar online](https://onlinegdb.com/gQxydhRdL).